# The numbers get reversed when use of arabic language

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-localization

I am using laravel localization

Here is the code I am using

```
<p class="retail-price">@lang('frontend/watch-detail.Reference.retail')
     <span class="prices">
     @if($watch['price'] == 0 || $watch['price'] == NULL) N/A

     @else
         @php
         $text =number_format($watch['price'], 0, ',', ' ');
         @endphp
         {{$text}}
     @endif
     </span>
</p>
```

Here is what I get in arabic =>[Image that I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MiVZ.png)

While I should get 30 700!

I do not want to use a reverse function

Comment: Post text, not images.

Comment: @RobG This is a display issue. It's impossible to convey with text alone.

Comment: Impossible? You seem to be writing "30 700" to the page and getting "700 30" instead. It's not that difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That issue occurs because Arabic is read from right to left. It would be easier to add an `if` statement to check if it *is* Arabic, then reverse it, so the reversed Arabic writing is reversed back to non-reversal.

Comment: I would be interested if anybody has a different solution

Comment: In Arabic, numbers are read left-to-right even though text is read right-to-left (I can't see the image). I guess you're saying that  the number is being reversed, so the OP should reverse it first so it's re–reversed?

Comment: Yes @RobG that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the text in a [*bdo* element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/bdo) and define it as left-to-right:

```js
function changeDir() {
  var el = document.getElementById('bdo0');
  el.dir = el.dir == 'ltr'? 'rtl':'ltr';
  document.getElementById('theDir').textContent = el.dir;
}
```

```html
<div dir="rtl">هذا رقم: <bdo id="bdo0" dir="ltr">123 456 789</bdo></div>
<button onclick="changeDir()">Change direction</button><span id="theDir"></span>
```

You shouldn't need any in–page script, it should be just HTML.